# A radical equation $(2x+1)^{2/3}+(2x-1)^{2/3}-2x^{2/3}=2^{1/3}$

Tags: polynomials, groebner-basis, radical-equations

Solve the equation $(2x+1)^{2/3}+(2x-1)^{2/3}-2x^{2/3}=2^{1/3}$.
I am looking for real roots. The graph of the equation tell us there are 4 solutions: roughly at $\pm0.09, \pm 1.64$, but I want to know if the roots can be found through algebraic manipulations. I tried letting $u=(2x+1)^{1/3}, v = (2x-1)^{1/3}$ and then reduce the equation to an expression with integer exponent, but the result doesn't seem to factorize easily. My guess is that there is some clever transformation which turns this equation to a quadratic or a cubic equation. Can anyone help?

Comment: Where does the equation come from, are you looking for real vs. complex roots, and is there a reason to expect "nice" roots?

Comment: @dxiv I was asked by a friend to solve this equation, I was telling her the same thing: this equation may not have a closed form solution...I thought I should ask here just to see if anyone could come up with a clever solution.

Comment: @dxiv I am looking for real roots, but I feel that it shouldn't be a big issue. Actually the graph of the equation can tell us there are 4 real roots. The problem is whether we can find them using algebra manipulation.

Comment: Turns out you can, though it would still be relevant to know where the equation actually originated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write it as:

$$
\sqrt[3]{(2x+1)^2} + \sqrt[3]{(2x-1)^2} = 2\sqrt[3]{x^2} + \sqrt[3]{2}
$$

Cube both sides using $(a+b)^3=a^3+b^3+3ab(a+b)$:

$$
\require{cancel}
(\cancel{4x^2}+\xcancel{4x}+\cancel{1}) + (\cancel{4x^2}-\xcancel{4x}+\cancel{1}) + 3\sqrt[3]{(2x+1)^2(2x-1)^2}\bcancel{\left(\sqrt[3]{(2x+1)^2} + \sqrt[3]{(2x-1)^2}\right)}
\\ = \cancel{8x^2} + \cancel{2} + 6\sqrt[3]{2x^2}\bcancel{\left(2\sqrt[3]{x^2} + 2^{1/3}\right)}
$$

Cube again:

$$
\begin{align}
27(4x^2-1)^2 &= 432 x^2
\\ 16 x^4 - 24 x^2 + 1 &= 0
\end{align}
$$

The latter is a biquadratic in $x$ with $4$ real roots.

---

[ *EDIT* ] $\;$ Verification using WA's GroebnerBasis [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=GroebnerBasis%5B%7Bu+%2B+v+-+2+w+-+z%2C+u%5E3-%282x%2B1%29%5E2%2C+v%5E3+-+%282x+-+1%29%5E2%2C+w%5E3+-+x%5E2%2C+z%5E3+-+2%7D%2C+%7Bx%7D%2C+%7Bu%2C+v%2C+w%2C+z%7D%5D).

---

[ *EDIT #2* ] $\;$ Canceling the factors in parentheses in the second step assumes that they are not zero. It is straightforward to verify that the simultaneous equations $\sqrt[3]{(2x+1)^2} + \sqrt[3]{(2x-1)^2}$ $= 2\sqrt[3]{x^2} + \sqrt[3]{2} = 0$ have no real root, so the cancelation is justified. This, however, explains why the WA solution includes the complex roots $x = \pm \frac{i}{2}\,$.

Comment: Nice, I thought about cubing both sides, but somehow rejected the idea because I thought this was a dead end...Thanks!

Comment: @SeanIan Equations of the form $\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}=\sqrt[3]{c}+\sqrt[3]{d}$ are not pretty to "algebraize" in general. What made this one workable was $a+b=c+d$.